# Import posts from a different database with the same old id

Tags: plugins, posts, functions, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from an old custom programming to a new WordPress site, but I encountered a problem that I cannot retrieve the old id number. I need that to keep the site's archive, the number of posts is more than 10,000.

> I want to move from a custom programming to a new WordPress blog, and
> I want to use the post ID to redirect links

I have tried the wp all import plugin, but it does not give the option to enter the id, but there is the option to add lines of code I don't know if it will help.

Is there a solution? Or a hint?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The post ID I assume you mean? What are you trying to do to retrieve the old ID? Why do you need the old post ID? You may also run into a problem where the IDs of your old site conflict with the IDs of the new site.

Comment: I want to move from a custom programming to a new WordPress blog, and I want to use the post ID to redirect links